# Can't see OData fields in API return object when using paging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, .net-6.0

I am creating an API in .NET 6 that returns a IQueryable object fetch from a database using o-data filters. I've managed to enable the odata filters and I can now run queries in the database by hitting the API endpoint. The issue I am running into now is that I would like to enable paging in the API response, but when I turn on this parameter I do not get a "next" field in the API response as I would expect. Here is a sample endpoint :

```
[HttpGet("CosmosTestIQueriable")]
[EnableQuery(PageSize =2)]
public ActionResult UseIqueriable()
{   
    var result = this.container.GetItemLinqQueryable<CosmosItem>(true);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

`This is the code I use to configure OData in my service:`

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddOData(options => options
                    .Select()
                    .Filter()
                    .OrderBy()
                    .SetMaxTop(100)
                    .Count())
    .AddODataNewtonsoftJson();
```

By turning on `[EnableQuery(PageSize =2)]`, the API does cap the number of results to 2, but I don't think it is possible for the user to query the next page with this method. Am I using the wrong method for enabling this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add option `SkipToken`

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddOData(options => options
                    .Select()
                    .Filter()
                    .OrderBy()
                    .SetMaxTop(100)
                    .SkipToken()
                    .Count())
    .AddODataNewtonsoftJson();
```

Comment: This didn't work. The SkipToken() method makes it so that the client can use the "skip" query option when using your API.